# Can I tell if `ssh` is suspended client side?

Tags: ssh, signals

Can I tell if the client `ssh` is suspended?

Let us assume I run:

```
ssh server command
```

and in another window

```
killall -STOP ssh
```

Can `command` somehow detect this? I would imagine it could detect it by sending lots data stdout/stderr and if that blocks, then it would indicate that the client program was suspended.

But can it be done without sending data to stderr/stdout?

**Background**

When GNU Parallel runs remote jobs, these commit suicide when the master dies. This is done using a wrapper, and it works nicely. But if the master is only suspended, the remote jobs do not suspend. If I from the remote end can detect that the master is suspended, then I can make a wrapper that will suspend the job.

Comment: Note that while SIGSTOP can't be intercepted, it's rare for a SIGSTOP to be sent to a process. Processes are more commonly suspended with signals like SIGTSTP (^Z), or SIGTTIN (background job reading from the terminal). And those can be intercepted (for instance to tell the remote command that you're being suspended by some mean).

Answer (score 2):

No ([but there might be another way to solve your problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). It's impossible, from outside the client, to distinguish a suspended client process from a network link that's dropping or delaying packets.